# get value of mysql db by random

Tags: php, mysql

I want a code to get database row 
I have table->(site) and two Columns->(url,rank)

rank should more than 0

I run this code :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$queryt  = "SELECT url FROM site WHERE rank>0 ORDER By RAND() LIMIT 1";
$resultt = mysql_query($queryt) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultt)) {
echo $row['url'];
}
```

but say (database not selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using mysqli connection like so

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
mysqli_select_db($con,"test"); // not compulsory
```

Or try telling mysqli to throw exceptions

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
         $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;
    } catch (Exception $e ) {
         echo "Service unavailable";
         echo "message: " . $e->message;   // not in live code obviously...
         exit;
```

Also you are using `mysqli` to connect and `mysql` to query database, there is a difference among both

Hope it helps !

Comment: Using mysqli no need mysqli_select_db I think

Comment: See the base firm http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: Yes the first one is default but with mysqli_select_db you can change your database

Comment: oh yes problem mysql shoud mysqli this worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the connection in param:

```
$resultt = mysqli_query($conn,$queryt) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Put this at the end of your query: mysqli_close($conn);

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem before and solved it with prefixing the table name with the database name, so

```
 select * from database.table
```